# Figure margins too large on TraMineR plot

Tags: graph, traminer

Im trying to graph types as shown here http://traminer.unige.ch/preview-typology.shtml

I can only fit 8 types in my screen until i get the error `Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`. That´s as far as my UI goes, I can't make the graph interface any taller.

I'm trying to make more types, is there any way I can do this?

This is the plot I'm trying to do.

`seqIplot(f3.seq, group = cl1.4fac, sortv = "from.end",with.legend = "none", xtlab=c(rep(18:29, each = 1)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'Figure margins too wide' error is related to the graphic device you are using. It means that the margins do not leave enough place for the figure itself.

There are several possible workarounds (that can possibly be combined).

1. Changing the number of columns of the graphical area by means of the `cols` argument of the `seqplot` function.
2. Reducing the size of the tick marks labels (`cex.axis` argument), of the title (`cex.main` argument) and suppressing axis labels.
3. Suppressing the y and x axes (`axes` and `yaxis` arguments).
4. Changing the values of the margins (`par(mar=...)`).
5. Changing default parameters of the graphic device, e.g. play with the `width` and `height` values of `pdf()` or `png()`.

I illustrate the first four solutions below using the `mvad` data that ships with `TraMineR`.

```
library(TraMineR)
data(mvad)
mvad.labels <- c("employment", "further education", "higher education", 
                 "joblessness", "school", "training")
mvad.scode <- c("EM", "FE", "HE", "JL", "SC", "TR")
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[, 17:86], states = mvad.scode,
                   labels = mvad.labels, xtstep = 6)

diss <- seqdist(mvad.seq, method="LCS")
mvad.clus <- hclust(as.dist(diss), method="ward.D")
k <- 9
mvad.cl <- cutree(mvad.clus,k=k)

## changing text size and number of columns of graphical area   
seqdplot(mvad.seq, group=mvad.cl, border=NA, cols=3, 
         cex.axis=.5, cex.main=0.6, ylab='', xlab='')
```

[image]

```
## default margins are: par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)
## setting 0 margins except for top
opar <- par(mar=c(0, 0, 2, 0) + 0.1) 
seqdplot(mvad.seq, group=mvad.cl, border=NA,  
         axes=FALSE, yaxis=FALSE)
par(opar) ## resetting default mar
```

[image]